# Automatically Copy the only Credit rows into a Sheet

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use a formula by the below, With out use Developer Options.

I have a excel workbook and there is a two sheets 
 One is -

One sheet is (sheet1)-

```
TXN. ID   Transection Type  After Balance
Biswa           Credit         271
55075491        Debit          170
Biswa           Credit         1195
55299322        Debit          1137
55506371        Debit          1101
1000006         Debit          1053
1438784910      Debit          1011
```

& i want to copy the only  credit rows into sheet 2.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far so we can see where it's gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure if this is what you're looking for, but as far as I understand your problem I see two options:

A) Set a filter/sort by Transaction Type and then just manually copy the output to your other sheet.

B) In your second sheet use an IF-formula, to check wether the corresponding row has the word "Credit" in column 2. Example for cell A1 in sheet 2:

=if(Sheet1!$B1="Credit";Sheet1!$A1;"")

You can then autofill/copy this formula down as needed. Note: This will leave blank rows (of course) - but you could in turn again filter/sort by "non-empty" fields, thus eliminating the empty rows.

Hope this helps!
Michael